# Numerical Mathematics - Constraint or Unconstraint Optimization?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

A function should be minimized w.r.t. a matrix that has to be positive definite. To ensure positive definiteness, there are two options:

1. Write a wrapper function that takes the cholesky decompostion as input and feeds the resulting p.d. matrix into the original function. Then do **unconstraint** minimization of the wrapper function.
2. Do **constraint** minimization on the original function, by e.g. imposing positive eigenvalues.

Which of the two options is better?

Comment: why don't you just use a SDP solver?  Your question as it currently stands is too vague to give you an answer.

Comment: @Thoth Sorry for being too vague. Actually, I am hoping for a quite general statement. In general, is it better to use constraint optimization or to cleverly implement the restrictions with unconstraint optimization? Another example would be imposing non-negativity on a scalar parameter. You simply square the input argument at the beginning of the function and then take the square root of the optimum or you could impose non-negativity in constraint optimization. Which of the two generally works better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you reinvent the wheel, do note that optimization over semidefinite matrices (semidefinite programming) is a very well established field with lots of theory, applications, and generally available solvers.

Essentially all methods to solve these problems work in what you could say is your category (2), by using (typically) interior-point primal-dual solvers. Practical examples include SeDuMi, SDPA,SDPT3, CSDP, Mosek, DSDP, etc.

There is one singular exception though, and that is a method proposed by Burer and Monteiro (implmented in the solver SDPLR). Here they parameterize the matrix using a factorized representation as you describe in (1). This leads to a non-convex problem (in contrast to the underlying problem which is convex), but surprisingly it performs well, and it has recently been analysed further, and it has been proven that it does not suffer from local minima, despite non-convexity.